# Persistently store list items added by user in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am very new to swift (as in I started today) and I have code that allows the user to add items to a list:

```
private func onAdd() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Enter a name for your plant", message: "Make sure it's descriptive!", preferredStyle: .alert)
       alert.addTextField { (textField) in
           textField.placeholder = "Enter here"
       }
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default) { _ in
        let textField = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
        plantName2 = textField.text ?? "Name"
        appendItem()
    })
       showAlert(alert: alert)
}

private func appendItem() {
    items.append(Item(title: plantName2))
}
```

and

```
struct HomePage: View {
@State var plantName2: String = ""
@State private var items: [Item] = []
@State private var editMode = EditMode.inactive
private static var count = 0

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("My Plants")) {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: PlantView(plantName3: item.title)) {
                        Text(item.title)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: onDelete)
                .onMove(perform: onMove)
                .onInsert(of: [String(kUTTypeURL)], perform: onInsert)
            }
        }
        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle()) // or GroupedListStyle
        .navigationBarTitle("Plantify")
        .navigationBarTitleTextColor(CustomColor.pastelGreen)
        .navigationBarItems(leading: EditButton().accentColor(CustomColor.pastelGreen), trailing: addButton)
        .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
    }
}
```

and I want the entries the user adds to be saved in persistent storage. I've looked at the docs for persistent storage and am a bit confused. Is it even possible with the code I have?

Thanks!

Comment: Persistent storage is incredibly vague. You have to Pick one. CoreData, JSON file, Remote Database, etc. You are also mixing SwiftUI and UIKit but not showing how you mix them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can save the data as String array in `UserDefaults`

```
func save() {
   UserDefaults.standard.set(items.map(\.title), forKey: "items")
} 

func load() {
   let savedItems = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "items") ?? []
   items = savedItems.map(Item.init)
}
```

and call `load` in `.onAppear`.

However if there is a huge amount of items consider a file in the Documents folder or Core Data